# Magento 2 - Don't want to remove wishlist items when click 'Add all to cart' button

Tags: magento2, addtocart, wishlist

I want to keep items in wishlist when user click "add all to cart" button. Have any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 5):

Magento adds wishlist items to the cart using the `addToCart()` method on the wishlist `Item` class. This method has a parameter that specifies whether to also remove the item from the wishlist. You can add a plugin to this to force this parameter to always be false.

Add this to a custom module `di.xml`, replacing `Namespace\Module` with your module name:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Wishlist\Model\Item">
        <plugin name="keep_in_wishlist" type="Namespace\Module\Plugin\KeepItemsInWishlistOnPurchase" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Then add this plugin to your module:

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;
use Magento\Wishlist\Model\Item;

class KeepItemsInWishlistOnPurchase
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Item $item
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart
     * @return array
     */
    public function beforeAddToCart(Item $item, Cart $cart)
    {
        return [$cart, false];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> AS OF NOW 18 JAN 2020 this observer is not useful, please have a look on [@scotts's answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/301519/45519)

This is Magento's default functionality, when a product is added to cart it it removed from the wishlist.

You can update this functionality in observer `vendor/magento/module-wishlist/Observer/AddToCart.php`

which is triggered by **checkout_cart_add_product_complete** event in `vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart/Add.php` controller.

To stop products removal from wishlist you have to disable this core observer by following way.

Your custom-module's `Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_add_product_complete">
        <observer name="wishlist" disabled="true"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

Comment: This will not work because this observer no longer does anything. It is a deprecated holdover from Magento 1, and old Magento 1 at that. It handles requests to the standard add-to-cart controller (different from the regular wishlist add-to-cart controller) that include the `wishlist_next` URL parameter, which per this answer was removed in Magento 1.4: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/253200/567

Comment: @ScottBuchanan Thanks for the update...

Answer (score 0):

Please check this extension that matches your ask https://marketplace.magento.com/decryptweb-wishlist.html